# Perl first line read in from a CSV file doesn't match correctly against ^ regex

Tags: regex, perl

Really weird one here.

The following code works correctly on one computer running perl 5.26, yet fails on one running 5.22 and another running 5.28.

The perl code is

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

sub filterSpeachMarksFromTextElementsInArray ($) {
    my ($arrayRef) = @_;
    foreach my $element  (@$arrayRef) {
        print "[$element]";
        if ($element =~ /^"(.*)"$/) {
            $element = $1;
        }
    }
}

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Must specify a file to load in\n"; #TODO build a proper usage type function. 

open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

# Read in csv into an array of headers and rows
my $lineCount = 0;
my @headers =();
my @rows = ();
while (my $line = <$data>){
    chomp $line;
    $lineCount ++;
    if ($lineCount == 1) {
        @headers = split ',', $line;
    } else {
        my @row = split ',' , $line;
        push @rows, \@row;
    }

}
print "Printing headers before regex";
print Dumper(@headers);
print "\n-----------------\n Stripping qutoes\n";
&filterSpeachMarksFromTextElementsInArray(\@headers);
print "Printing headers after regex\n";
print Dumper(@headers);
print "\nFinished!\n";
```

This is the test csv I'm giving it :

```
"Submitted At","Do you have any images to upload","What would you like to say about this image? ",PDFs,"Total Amount","Customer ID","IP Address",ID,"UTM Source","UTM Medium","UTM Campaign","UTM Term","UTM Content","Device Type"
"2019-07-05 00:47:44",https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/paperform/u-28769/0/2019-07-05/ih2348a/zhdfbwvbc2miyqyaryl9.jpg,"This is a picture of a dog. ",,0," -",125.236.132.186,5d1e9e30f76b5c056961e585,,,,,,desktop
```

Running with

```sh
perl test.pl test.csv
```

I get

```
Printing headers before regex$VAR1 = '"Submitted At"';
$VAR2 = '"Do you have any images to upload"';
$VAR3 = '"What would you like to say about this image? "';
$VAR4 = 'PDFs';
$VAR5 = '"Total Amount"';
$VAR6 = '"Customer ID"';
$VAR7 = '"IP Address"';
$VAR8 = 'ID';
$VAR9 = '"UTM Source"';
$VAR10 = '"UTM Medium"';
$VAR11 = '"UTM Campaign"';
$VAR12 = '"UTM Term"';
$VAR13 = '"UTM Content"';
$VAR14 = '"Device Type"';

-----------------
 Stripping qutoes
["Submitted At"]["Do you have any images to upload"]["What would you like to say about this image? "][PDFs]["Total Amount"]["Customer ID"]["IP Address"][ID]["UTM Source"]["UTM Medium"]["UTM Campaign"]["UTM Term"]["UTM Content"]["Device Type"]Printing headers after regex
$VAR1 = '"Submitted At"';
$VAR2 = 'Do you have any images to upload';
$VAR3 = 'What would you like to say about this image? ';
$VAR4 = 'PDFs';
$VAR5 = 'Total Amount';
$VAR6 = 'Customer ID';
$VAR7 = 'IP Address';
$VAR8 = 'ID';
$VAR9 = 'UTM Source';
$VAR10 = 'UTM Medium';
$VAR11 = 'UTM Campaign';
$VAR12 = 'UTM Term';
$VAR13 = 'UTM Content';
$VAR14 = 'Device Type';

Finished!
```

You'll notice that the first header line still has the quotes around it. Yet running the same script on another computer running 5.26 the quotes are removed. WHY?

I can fix this by changing the regex to

```perl
if ($element =~ /"(.*)"$/) {
$element = $1;
}
```

Dropping the start of string match. This doesn't really matter I can get this working other ways. (Also I know I should be using string replace not an if). But I can't sleep at night not knowing what is going on here?

**EDIT:** 
**Shawn** has found the problem. I'm not handling the byte order mark at the start of the file.

```sh
cat test.csv | xxd
00000000: efbb bf22 5375 626d 6974 7465 6420 4174  ..."Submitted At
00000010: 222c 2244 6f20 796f 7520 6861 7665 2061  ","Do you have a
00000020: 6e79 2069 6d61 6765 7320 746f 2075 706c  ny images to upl
```

Shows the UTF-8 "EF BB BF".

When using :

```perl
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

as suggested by **ikegami**. The output changes to show this extra part of the string

```
$VAR1 = "\x{feff}\"Submitted At\"";
```

Comment: 1) 5.22, 5.26 and 5.28 all produce the correct output for the code and data you provided.

Comment: 2) You are (badly) re-implenting Text::CSV_XS / Text::CSV_PP

Comment: Does the csv file have a Unicode byte order mark sequence at the beginning?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sure Shawn found the issue. `$line =~ s/^\x{FEFF}// if $. == 1;` will fix that (assuming you first correctly decode the file (e.g. possibly by adding `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`))

Comment: ikegami for point 2. You are very correct this is not the correct way to do it. This is only something I was messing around with and happened across this bug. This is a very simplified version, trying to use as few libs as possible to reproduce this. 

Point 1, this seems to be a pattern I've tried on 3 computers. It works on 1 and fails on two. Perhaps it is not the perl version. Thanks for trying. I may need to put  together a docker image that reliably reproduces this.

Comment: ikegami and Shawn Thanks! that explains it. If one of you want's to answer this I'll mark that as the correct one. If not I'll throw up an explanation in a couple of days and give credit to you two.

Comment: Isn't the BOM only relavent on utf-16 encodings ? But your supposed to test the file encoding first right ? I mean _guess_ the enconding.

Comment: @sh Some tools add a BOM to utf-8 as an easy way to indicate that the text is utf-8. Iirc, you see it more on Windows than Linux or Unix systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a regular expression that *should* match at the start of a string and doesn't, one explanation is that there's some characters at the start of the line that aren't being displayed by your editor or whatever other tool you're using to look at the content. When it only happens on the first line of a file, while later lines match appropriately, odds are pretty decent that the file is encoded using UTF-8 and whatever created the file put a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file. It's not needed for UTF-8, but it's not unheard of.

Looking at your file in a hex editor showed that this was indeed the case. The fix is to explicitly tell perl the file is encoded using UTF-8:

```
open(my $data, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
```

or alternatively like you did, using `use open` to change the default encoding for files in that scope.

Unfortunately, the UTF-8 decoder doesn't automatically strip the BOM, but you can just get rid of that leading `\x{FEFF}` code point manually. ikegami's suggestion of `$line =~ s/^\x{FEFF}// if $. == 1` works well when reading from a file.

Another option uses the [File::BOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::BOM) module off of CPAN:

```
open(my $data, '<:encoding(UTF-8):via(File::BOM)', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
```

or

```
open_bom(my $data, $file); # Croaks on failure
```

which *does* transparently remove the mark if present so you don't have to do so manually.